# C# creating a wrapper namespace?

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces

In C#, how can I import all classes from one namespace into another namespace such that these classes are directly accessible from the second namespace?

I'm essentially attempting to rename a namespace in an externally visible manner.

Since code is worth a thousand words, given a DLL with the following namespace:

```cs
// Externally written DLL I have no control over.

namespace A
{
    class ClassA {...}
}
```

I'd like to be able to create another DLL along the lines of:

```cs
// My DLL

namespace Wrapper
{
    using A;
}
```

So that I can use it like:

```cs
// Final C# program.

using Wrapper;

var a = ClassA();
```

In python, I could accomplish what I want with `import *`:

```py
# external.py
class ClassA:
    ...
```

```py
# mymodule.py
from external import *
```

```py
# final_program.py
import mymodule
a = mymodule.ClassA()
```

### Disclaimer

I know this is a terrible idea, but I'm unfortunately being constrained by external requirements. The short version is that I have an external DLL that needs to interface with a proprietary system (EnScript, if you're curious). This proprietary system has restrictions on the naming of namespaces that the external DLL of course violates. Thus, I'm attempting to use the wrapper DLL to expose a namespace that is considered valid.

### Related Questions

Talks about `using` in C# vs wildcard imports in java/python. Does not address issue of accessing from second namespace:

- [Import all subclasses like Java but in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060379/import-all-subclasses-like-java-but-in-c-sharp)
- [C# equivalent to wildcard imports in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583944/c-sharp-equivalent-to-wildcard-imports-in-java)
- [Namespaces in C# vs imports in Java and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767910/namespaces-in-c-sharp-vs-imports-in-java-and-python)

Question about including classes in namespace. Issue was use of separate projects and so not applicable to this question:

- [How To Include Classes From Another Namespace In Assembly Instead of Writing Them Into A Separate DLL File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931489/how-to-include-classes-from-another-namespace-in-assembly-instead-of-writing-the)

Comment: I had originally suggested you use Type Forwarding but after running a little test model, this will not work for you since the one requirement is that the namespace stays the same, something you cannot have. It looks like your best option is going to be to create shell classes that forward requests to the real class in the other assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move a type to a different namespace (other than physically moving the code). The .NET type system uses the full namespace to uniquely identify the type.

But you can create an alias to mask the original namespace.

Let's say you have a class `MyProject.Foo.Bar.Xyzzy.MyClass`, and you are tired of typing `MyProject.Foo.bar.Xyzzy`.  You can add a [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) directive at the top of the code file like this:

```
Using DifferentNamespace = MyProject.Foo.Bar.Xyzzy;
```

Once you have done this, you can refer to the class  with just

```
var c = new DifferentNamespace.MyClass();
```

You can even use this to include a different namespace in the current default namespace.  This will compile:

```
namespace Example.Classes
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}

namespace Example
{
    using Example = Example.Classes;
    class Test
    {
        static void Test1()
        {
            var c = new Example.MyClass();  //Not Example.Classes.MyClass
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately you have to leave the alias there; i.e., this won't compile:

```
namespace Example.Classes
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}

namespace Example
{
    using Example = Example.Classes;
    class Test
    {
        static void Test1()
        {
            var c = new MyClass();  //Error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I access the alias from outside the `Example` namespace? Because this is what I unfortunately need to do.

Comment: You can access it in any code module by putting `using Example = Example.Classes` at the top along with your other using directives.

Comment: Problem is, I'm ultimately accessing from a proprietary scripting engine, not C#. This proprietary scripting engine can call into .NET DLLs, but does not actually run in .NET. (It's complicated, but it's unfortunately what I have to use due to business requirements.)